# Bulk testing being restricted by limitation with Database.batchExecute() - How to overcome?

Tags: trigger, unit-test, batch

I was getting an occasional UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW error when two records were saved very close to each other. Related records were getting locked by one trigger invocation, and a second trigger invocation would sometimes have to wait more than 10 seconds in order to obtain the lock on those records, after which the error was thrown.

In order to prevent this, I've had to call a batch job from within the trigger, so that the processing can be done in smaller batches.

This is working well, but has an annoying side-effect that I now cannot run bulk tests with large numbers of records, because `Database.executeBatch()` can only be called once per testing invocation, otherwise the following error will be thrown:

> System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method. Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.

If the number of records in the test is more than the maximum 200 per trigger invocation, or even if it is more than the batch size specified in the `Database.executeBatch()`, then the error occurs.

I really want to be able to test with bulk quantities of records, but can't seem to find a way around this restriction. Is there anyway to get around this?

**Edit**

Object Relationships (via lookups):

Issue <- Booking <- BookingLine

When a status is changed on an Issue, it is necessary to update a field on all of its related BookingLines, and then information is to flow up to change fields in the related Bookings.

If there are 600 BookingLines for an Issue, that means that there will be 3 BookingLine trigger invocations when someone updates the Issue (because a maximum of 200 records can be in a single trigger invocation).

The related Booking objects are locked while this is happening, so if someone saves a ***second*** Issue with another 600 BookingLines, it is possible that the three resulting trigger invocations will also want to get the lock for Bookings that are already locked, and if there is a wait of more than 10 seconds, then the error occurs.

Cutting the updates to the BookingLines into smaller chunks doesn't *guarantee* that a locking error won't occur, but it does reduce the chance of locking both because if the Apex job limit is 5 and the batch size is small enough, then we will have a lower chance of any jobs waiting for a lock. Plus, with smaller jobs, fewer records will actually be locked at any one time reducing the risk of two invocations wanting access to it at the same time.

Comment: Can you share at least an outline of your trigger structure? Calling a batch process from a trigger to avoid row-locking may not be the optimal solution to the original problem (for reasons like this).

Comment: Hi David. Do you mean the relationships between the different objects? Or actual trigger code?

Comment: The trigger code, although knowing the relationships may help understand where the source of the row locking is.

Comment: Refer this knowledge article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000330685&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Thanks @RohitMourya. I've read that, but while it prevents the error from being thrown it doesn't help me accurately test because the updates should happen on all records in the bulk test.

Comment: @DavidReed - Thanks David. I've added some more details.